# How to avoid scrolling when softkeyboard appears

Tags: android

In my application, when soft keyboard appears, this pushes entire layout up. I am ok when it scrolls up. But there are 2 buttons at the top of the layout that should not be scrolled!

Any clue is helpful

Comment: before giving down votes please mention reasons

Comment: Ya i am using full screen activity. when i used adjust resize it squeezes entire layout. And if used adjustpan it pushes entire layout